# Best way to organize TCP-like channel with server in WebAssembly in C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, networking, webassembly

I'm very new to [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), and decided to try compiling [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) C++ application for wasm target.

All graphical UI part works fine in browser. But now I need to create some bytes channel between server (that serves web traffic) and wasm application. I need two simple methods:

```cpp
channel.Send(bytes);
bytes res = channel.Recv();
```

Basically I need to be able to send block of bytes (of any not too big size) and receive block of bytes to and from server. Sometimes data is quite large, even hundreds of megabytes, of course split into many smaller chunks.

Connection should be kept alive. I plan to send/recv from time to time, sometimes once in few seconds, sometimes once in a few minutes. Even if I don't send for few minutes still connection should be kept alive.

Basically the procedure is as follows - client side (wasm web page) sends Open request to server somehow, server creates a separate C++ process in Linux or Windows environment. Then this process should be able to send and receive blocks of bytes of any nature and size. Whenever connection is closed this signifies that client has quit and working process is terminated. Connection is closed (and process terminated) only if client Quits application (or very long time of inactivity passes, like 1 hour), or if server is sure that client closed the web page.

So my question is what is the best way to organize such channel? Is there some special class in Qt for that? Also as I understand another question is due to Browser security, because not any TCP connection can be made for sure, so I need to use some restricted API for that.

I heard there is [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) technology, but never learnt or used it. Also as I understand regular [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) connection somehow can be kept alive and used to send/recv any blocks of bytes, right?

Comment: You will need to add JavaScript code to expose the browser WebSockets to your WebAssembly blob.

Comment: @Botje Actually before using websockets I thought it would be good to use some generic and more simple solution. You know why? Because if I don't depend on any browser technology then I can compile my application with desktop target instead of wasm. Hence my desktop application can be used with same server to do same tasks. It is very benefitial for me to have cross platform application.

Comment: That is very noble, but browsers only support Websockets as lowest-level communication. And Qt has had `QWebSocket` since 5.3.

Comment: @Botje What if I open HTTP connection to server with Keep-Alive setting and send bytes back and forth through this connection? Is it possible? Looks like cross platform solution, because with Desktop compilation of project I still can do same HTTP connection without browser.

Comment: That's basically 70% of what Websockets are. And WebSockets are of course available on native programs as well...